# Live copy text from TinyMCE to the hidden textarea it is connected to?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

The problem I'm experiencing with TinyMCE is that it keeps my hidden textarea (it becomes hidden as TinyMCE is inited) empty until the form it is in is submitted.

I realize that it can be done with callbacks and stuff like that, but it would be overhead if there were a built-in way to do that, so I'm asking is there one?

P.S. This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958140/tinymce-live-copy-text-from-tinymce-to-regular-text-field) because it's been quite a big while since it was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer today is essentially the same as the one you linked to only there is a built in TinyMCE API to do the update.

TinyMCE does not keep the underlying `<textarea>` in sync at all times. Normally, when you post the form, TinyMCE will update the `<textarea>` right before the form is posted.  You can use the following API call to force TinyMCE to update the `<textarea>`:

```
tinymce.triggerSave();
```

This will force TinyMCE to update the `<textarea>` when its called.

TinyMCE fires a variety of events and you can choose to use any number of these events as the trigger for the update:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/

For example this would update the editor on the `change` or `blur` events:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change blur', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I've already written a similar [thing](https://pastebin.com/dmBvmutc), which copies the text from the editor to the textarea as the user types.